# Prevent exposed override methods to Swift header

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am rewriting an Objective-C project in Swift. I've gotten far with the interoperability of Swift and Objective-C, MixAndMatch documentation, and converted good number of classes.

Here is the interesting scenario; I have a model class written in Swift

```
class FooModel {
    @objc override func create(_ data: [String: [String: Any]]) {
       ...
    }
}
```

When it's exposed to ProjectModuleName-Swift.h for access from ObjC code

```
-(void)create:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSDictionary *> * _Nonnull)data;
```

It accepts a parameter of type dictionary which can have a string key and dictionary value.

When calling it from Objective-C code, if I pass a dictionary with a string key and a different value type it's crashing. Because the Swift expects a dictionary for every value.

How can I control the function when it's exposed to swift header OR guarantee that @nonobjc does not break the method call?

I tried adding `@nonobjc` to the method, so it isn't exposed to Swift. It works for one model class, but not for all. When I am adding it into some, the method is not even being called anymore.

Comment: Have you tried using `[String: Dictionary]` or `[String: NSDictionary]` instead of `[String: [String: Any]`?

Comment: @Malik: Thanks for mentioning.. That function is override function coming from OBJC code. Actually, I can't change those global APIs  which is already being developed ... !! And by the way, Just Dictionary is not allowed in Swift, compiler will show error to change it to perticular type.. we have to specify type.